# Scan Mounted Ext3 File System on runtime

Tags: linux, sles

We have SUSE Linux system where we have various partitions, and we are facing corruption of FS.
We are now trying to scan FS periodically without rebooting the system and we have gone through fsck option but on Man page we came to know we cannot use because result will not be reliable on Mounted partitions.
So can someone help me with any sort of method to use to scan mounted file system that avoids reboot of system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is little tooling for online consistency checking of filesystems *because it is never part of reasonable business practices*.

Your filesystem should, by default, not go bad unnoticed. If it did go bad, your hardware is bad or your disk size / error rate is not mitigated by appropriate RAID levels. Or, more rarely, your OS has a bug.

These days, storage hardware is best **replaced at the earliest indication of failure**, ideally before data loss occurs. Install new storage, test your RAM and only then, on the now-redundant original storage media you can work on figuring out whether the media spontaneously failed, or whether your monitoring was bad and tools like SMART could have provided an early warning. You don't do this on a live production system, and not without rebooting.